# Determine which if statement was triggered? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

how would I determine which if statement was triggered?

Example:

```
string = "hello"
if len(string) > 10:
    print("over 10")

elif string == "hello":
    print("String is equal to hello")

else:
    pass
```

I want to rewrite it so its more "pythonic", I have gotten this far

```
string = "hello"
if len(string) > 10 or string == "hello":
    print("one of the if statements was triggered") # I want to determine which was triggered
else:
    pass
```

Is what I am hoping to accomplish even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I even don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: Not sure what you want. But if it prints out the `"one of the if statements was triggered"` then clearly that if statement was triggered. If it doesn't print anything then clearly it didn't meet the condition for the if statement and so it hopped to the else statement and didn't print anything.

Comment: The extremely hacky way would be to use list comprehension to evaluate the statements separately. Then you can find which element of the list is `True`, and that will tell you which was triggered I guess. This is a really clunky way of tackling it, though. I.e. `x=[], x.append(string=='hello')`, `x.append(string=='3')` and then `x.index(True)`?

Comment: BTW: Making it shorter / more concise != making it more Pythonic

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there is nothing wrong with the if statement you use.

But if you want to be clever you could use a list of `lambda`'s:

```
In [1]: string  = 'Hello'

In [2]: conditions = [lambda s: 'Length is > 10' if len(s) > 10 else None,
   ...:               lambda s: 'String is "Hello"' if s == 'Hello' else None]
```

The `conditions` are anonymous functions. They return a string describing the condition or `None` using the ternary operator.

This is slightly different from your `if`-statement in that it tests *all* the conditions.

We apply the functions to the string, filtering out the `None` values:

```
In [3]: results = [r for r in [c(string) for c in conditions] if r is not None]
```

The `results` is a list of strings describing conditions that apply to the string.

We print the results.

```
In [4]: for r in results:
   ...:         print(r)
   ...:         
String is "Hello"
```

This certainly makes good use of the possibilities that Python offers.

If you would consider this Pythonic is a matter of taste. :-) The original `if`-statement is shorter, and probably easier to read! Especially for someone new to Python.

However, if you want to test a lot of conditions this could be a good approach instead of a *huge* list of if-statements.